# Gradle Project Version from build.gradle via Shell Bash Script

Tags: bash, shell, maven, gradle

I want to be able to grab the `build.gradle` version via a bash shell script that happens post build. How would I go about getting this?

For reference, in a Maven project, I achieve this task by using the following commmand: `mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression=project.version | grep -e '^[^\[]'`. What is it's equivalent for Gradle?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `properties` task can also do this.

```
./gradlew properties | grep ^version:
```

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: If you only want the version and not the prefix `version: ` modify the grep portion to `grep -Po '(?<=version: ).*'`.

Answer (score 4):

Either create a task in your build script that prints the version in the execution phase, then call that task also giving `-q` and you have only your version. Something like `task printVersion { doLast { logger.quiet version } }`.

If you don't want to modify your buildscript, you can write an init script instead that you either specify with `-i` manually when you need it or in `~/.gradle/init.d/` for always being applied that adds this task, then again call it giving `-q`.